# Appcelerator: Remote image not showing on Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, appcelerator

I have an issue with display remote image in my titanium app. I test on Nexus 5 android 6.0 and Simulator with android 6.0 too and result is the same, I have no image display. Beside android 6.0, other version working well.

Do you guys have any idea about this issue?

I'm using SDK 5.1.1.GA
And Build target is 23

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate known issues that we're working on fixing. Please follow progress on JIRA: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19899

Answer (score 0):

Maybe updated at Ti SDK 5.1.2 or 5.2.0

I've created a module temporarily.

https://github.com/gimdongwoo/Ti-Android-RequestStoragePermission